# Returning List with Children in ASP.NET CORE with firebase

Tags: c#, json, firebase, asp.net-core

I am trying to do a get all with an ASP.NET Core project that uses [this firebase library](https://github.com/step-up-labs/firebase-database-dotnet) and I can't seem to return the children nested in an object. I have 3 classes: Route, Via & Waypoints(Serves as a bridge for JSON Deserialization).

```
public class Route
    {
        public string Route_ID { get; set; }

        public string Destination { get; set; }
        public string Origin { get; set; }
        public Waypoints Stops { get; set; }


        public Route()
        {
        }
}
```

```
public class Via
    {
        public string Via_ID { get; set; }
        public string Route_ID { get; set; }
        public int Seq_Number { get; set; }
        public string Coordonnees { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }


        public Via()
        {

        }
}
```

```
public class Waypoints
    {
        public List<Via> Vias;

        public Waypoints()
        {

        }
    }
```

In my GET method I go Fetch everything from my Routes and want to return it as one JSON List containing all my routes along with their waypoints but it only returns an empty list of Waypoints:

```
[HttpGet]
        public async Task<IEnumerable<Route>> Get()
        {          


            List<Route> routes = (await firebaseClient
                .Child("routes")
                .OrderByKey()
                .OnceAsync<Route>())
                .Select(item =>
                        new Route
                        {
                            Route_ID = item.Key,
                            Origin = item.Object.Origin,
                            Destination = item.Object.Destination,
                            Waypoints = item.Object.Waypoints
                        }).ToList();
            
            foreach (Route route in routes)
            {
                List<Via> vias = (await firebaseClient
                    .Child("routes")
                    .Child(route.Route_ID)
                    .Child("Waypoints")
                    .OrderByKey()
                    .OnceAsync<Via>())
                    .Select(waypoint =>
                        new Via
                        {
                            Via_ID = waypoint.Key,
                            Route_ID = waypoint.Object.Route_ID,
                            Coordonnees = waypoint.Object.Coordonnees,
                            Seq_Number = waypoint.Object.Seq_Number,
                            Description = waypoint.Object.Description
                        }).ToList();

                if(vias.Count > 0)
                {
                    route.Stops.Vias = vias;
                }
                
            }
            return routes;
        }
```

My data structure:

```
{
  "routes" : {
    "987321": {
      "Destination": "13.13;-12.34",
      "Origin": "12.12;-12.12",
      "Route_ID": "987321",
      "Waypoints": {
        "4d5e6f": {
          "coordonnees": "45.8;-74.7",
          "description": "Description",
          "route_id": "987321",
          "seq_number": 2,
          "via_id": "4d5e6f"
        },
        "111222": {
          "coordonnees": "45.8;-74.7",
          "description": "Description",
          "route_id": "987321",
          "seq_number": 1,
          "via_id": "111222"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And finally my call result:

```
[
  {
    "route_ID": "987321",
    "destination": "13.13;-12.34",
    "origin": "12.12;-12.12",
    "waypoints": {}
  }
]
```

It seems the Deserializing doesn't go further than the first layer of children. Is there any solution to this?

Comment: Hi @Brandon P. , what about changing `public List<Via> Vias;` to `public List<Via> Vias{ get; set; }` in Waypoints model?

Comment: Apparently it was that easy! Silly mistake from my end but thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Rena's suggestion, I figured out that the problem was located in my Waypoints bridging class that was missing a { get; set; }

Here is the change that was made to my class:

```
public class Waypoints
{
    public List<Via> Vias { get; set; }

    public Waypoints()
    {

    }
}
```